# Is there any tag to know type of road/highway/route in OSRM RouteStep Object?

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

**Context** : I am querying OSRM to return route between two co-ordinates. It returns me requested route along with parts(steps) with instructions for route ( Array of RouteStep bjects in v5 ).

http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.6.4/api/#route-object

**What I want** : I want to know if there is way to know type of road for any particular RouteStep whether it is a motorway, highway, one way etc.

Any lead is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but in case people are still looking for an answer - road type information can be accessed for each step via the classes object inside the intersections object. 
Please do not use the hack outlined above (encoding the road type within the road name). This affects the routing itself.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not preserved beyond the initial pre-processing stage. A hack that I have seen some people use for this is to encode additional information in the street name.

For this you would need to modify `profiles/car.lua` (for example) and something like:

`result.name = "{highway: \"" .. data.highway .. "\", name:\"" .. result.name .. "\"}"` (disclaimer: I did not run this line in lua).

Answer (score 0):

The `Annotation` object has OSM *node* IDs but unfortunately no *way* IDs. It is possible to retrieve those nodes and determine the way ID(s) they belong to. The way contains the tags you are interested. Unfortunately this is not very feasible since it will require many individual requests.